# Getting Start date of the month only given with month and year in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, date

I have expiration date in one of my table as field. 
The expiration date is passed in the format of MMYY.  This should be handled accordingly with current DB scheme.  i.e. if 0516 is passed in, that represents May 1, 2016 in DB. And should save in this format. Any help how to get the start date of the that month and save into the db.

Comment: Do you still have the issue ? If not consider marking the answer as accepted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Rails:

```
d = Date.tomorrow
=> Tue, 02 Jul 2013
d.at_beginning_of_month
=> Mon, 01 Jul 2013
```

You need to instantiate a `Date` object with your custom date and then use the above method.